# Is this how time calculation for sorting algorithm analysis is done?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

Regarding bubble sort (or any sorting algorithm):
The question I got was:-

> Say the bubble sort takes 1 second (average) to sort an array with 1k elements. How much time will this implementation take to sort 8k elements?

My attempt was as follows, using O(n^2), where n=no. of elements. IDK if it's the correct approach or not.

> time = constant * (n)^2.

So in the case of my questions, I first calculated the constant and then used it in the formula with n=8000, giving the answer as 64 seconds. So 1=constant*(1000)^2 . Then the result into the above equation again, but with n=8k. Is this the correct approach/answer?
If the formula is correct, am I correct to assume that putting n*log_2 (n) instead of n^2 and then using the same method would give me correct answer for quicksort as well?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you doubt this is correct?

Comment: Do all values fit into the same cache level?

Comment: Are the arrays (partially) sorted already?

Answer (score 0):

Yes

if the you put 8 * n elements in the algorithm:

```
(8 * n)^2 = 8^2 + n^2 = 64 * n^2
```

Of cause the constant factor might not also grow, so it could be anything between
1s and 64s

Comment: "the constant factor might not also grow" sounds weird. What constant factor do you mean?

Comment: Thank you!! I had used the formula for "quicksort on 1k elements take 0.1s. So how many sec for 8k elements", and I got ≈1.04. And my freshman friend doing CS thought it was incorrect haha, so I got spooked (not a STEM major). Anyway, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @johnnydapper What did your friend think the time would be?